# Cannot add value to the y variable

Tags: java

Why do I get an error in `y=20`

```
class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=100;
        final int y=200;
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);

        x=10;
        y=20;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: final variable cannot be reassigned

Comment: Because it's final : http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword
You cant change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because y is a final variable. You can only onece add a value to the final variable. Just one time. And you've did that when create the variable.

final int y = 200;

for more information visit here http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword

Answer (score 5):

The `y` variable is marked as `final` which means it cannot be changed once set.

Answer (score 1):

when you put final before a variable or a method  or a class it means it can be changed again in an other place .
EX final y = 20 it will be always 20 you can't assign a new value for it .
you can read about it her : http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.tr/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html